# Ext JS/GWT Combobox

Tags: selenium, combobox

So I have a somewhat strange problem. 
I'm testing a GWT combobox with selenium and I'm having trouble executing the click command on a specific combo list value.
This is the code I am using:

```
selenium.click("//div[@id='My Id']/img");
selenium.waitForCondition("var value = selenium.isElementPresent('//div[contains(@class, \\'x-combo-list\\') and contains(@style, \\'visibility: visible\\')]'); value == true", "6000");
selenium.click("//div[contains(@class = 'x-combo-list')]/descendant::div[contains(@class = 'x-combo-list-item')][text()='cache']");
selenium.waitForCondition("var value = selenium.isElementPresent('//div[contains(@class, \\'x-combo-list\\') and contains(@style, \\'visibility: visible\\')]'); value == false", "7000");
```

This code clicks on the combo-box arrow, but it doesn't seem to click any value from the drop down list.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue using Selenium and also using Tellurium.

Finally, I created a jQuery statement that does the trick:

```
$('div.x-combo-list-item').filter(function(){return this.innerHTML.match('TestItem')}).trigger('mousedown');
```